# Find index of a dyn trait in Vector

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I need to find the index of an element, given by reference, in a vector that hold references to elements that satisfy a trait.

There is a layer system, which includes the layer trait and a layer stack (to have control over operations):

```rust
pub trait Layer {
  fn new(name: &str) -> Self where Self: Sized;

  fn on_attach(&mut self);
  fn on_detach(&mut self);
  fn on_update(&mut self);
  fn on_event(&mut self, event: &mut dyn Event);

  fn get_debug_name(&self) -> &String;
}

impl PartialEq for dyn Layer {
  fn eq(&self, other: &dyn Layer) -> bool {
    self.get_debug_name() == other.get_debug_name()
  }
}

pub struct LayerStack<'a> {
  layers: Vec<&'a mut dyn Layer>,
  overlay_position: usize,
}

impl<'a> LayerStack<'a> {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    Self {
      layers: Vec::new(),
      overlay_position: 0
    }
  }

  // ...

  pub fn find_index(&self, element: &'a dyn Layer) -> Option<usize> {
    self.layers.iter().position(|item| *item == element)
  }
}
```

There is an error in the `find_index` method:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
8  | impl<'a> LayerStack<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
48 |     self.layers.iter().position(|item| *item == element)
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
```

This is some kind of a lifetime issue but I can't see any problems here. What can I do about it?

I know that owning the elements themselves instead of references partly solves this problem, but I have to only have mutable ref to layers but not own them. Static lifetime in a struct generic also doesn't work: the layers don't have a static lifetime.

I'm a complete newbie at rust, so dealing with all the lifetime things is a complete nightmare

Comment: Have you tried `item == &element`?

Comment: I don't know which code produces this error but the code you've shared can be compiled, if you implement `PartialEq`, ofc you need to implement equality terms, here is the compiling code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16d5bf7b7f2b4acf70f4093369be5ef4

Comment: The problem is probably in your `PartialEq` implementation which you don't show. Please make sure and check that what you show here is a [mre].

Comment: @ÖmerErden , thank you so much! I had an implementation of `PartialEq` but I had no idea there could be a problem in it, as the compile error is apparently about lifetime. I didn't write that `... + '_` at `impl PartialEq for dyn Layer + '_`, adding this part solved the problem!

Comment: @cafce25, yes, you are absolutely right, I've edited the code example. I didn't add the implementation because I didn't realize this could be connected: the error was clearly about lifetimes, not about disability to compare, but the signature of the implementation didn't have a lifetime marker, so the compiler had no clue about the lifetimes of the objects.

Comment: Actually compiler is aware of the lifetime, it chooses the `'static` if you don't declare anything, and the `'a` you defined is not `'static` all the time. I can post an answer about this if you modify your question

Comment: @ÖmerErden, oh, now I get how it works, thank you! And I've also added the part with `PartialEq` implementation, I hope it's fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the implementation below; type expression(`dyn Layer`) is called as trait object.
(*need to note that `Layer` needs to be an [object safe trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety)*)

```rust
impl PartialEq for dyn Layer { /*...*/ }
```

Since `dyn Layer` is not used as a type argument of a generic type, Rust follows the rules below ([reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes):

> - If the trait is defined with a single lifetime bound then that bound
>   is used.
> - If 'static is used for any lifetime bound then 'static is used.
> - If the trait has no lifetime bounds, then the lifetime is inferred in expressions and ***is 'static outside of expressions.***

The highlighted part is applied to your implementation since there is no bound defined in the implementation you made.

Thus we can tell that your `PartialEq` implementation is only valid when the operands have static lifetime for `==` operator. But your operands live in `'a` which can be `'static` or something else.

```rust
impl<'a> LayerStack<'a> {
    //...
    pub fn find_index(&self, element: &'a dyn Layer) -> Option<usize> {
        self.layers.iter().position(|item| *item == element)
    }
```

To fix this problem we can apply the first rule (adding single lifetime bound)

```rust
impl<'a> PartialEq for dyn Layer + 'a { /*...*/ }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0fe19df8ccee93bd60722e63a0389357)

---

Or even better, from the reference above:

> If '_ is used as the lifetime bound then the bound follows the usual elision rules.

It can be implemented like this:

```rust
impl PartialEq for dyn Layer + '_ { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a full answer and for help to solve the problem!